# Problems on setting up rails server (4.2.4) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, ruby, rails

Noob question here. I've been trying to install Rails 4.2.4 on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I think I achieved it using RVM, but I'm not sure if everything needed is installed, because when I try to use the command: rails server (for setting a new app), this message appears:

```
    sara@sara:~/Escritorio/Rails/pinteresting$ rails server
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/home/sara/Escritorio/Rails/pinteresting/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

The most common rails commands are:
 generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console     Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server      Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 dbconsole   Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
             (short-cut alias: "db")
 new         Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
             new application called MyApp in "./my_app"

In addition to those, there are:
 destroy      Undo code generated with "generate" (short-cut alias: "d")
 plugin new   Generates skeleton for developing a Rails plugin
 runner       Run a piece of code in the application environment (short-cut alias: "r")

All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information
```

I don't know what to do. I have forgotten something at the installation? Maybe an aditional program needed?

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide an argument with your "rails server [ARGS]" command.

Comment: No, running `rails server` is just fine. In fact, I usually just do `rails s` which does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this on my Ubuntu 14.04.3 machine:

```
cd ~
rails new test-app
cd test-app
rails server
```

...and it starts right up. So it seems to me that you are having a problem with you app. Please try what I did and see how it goes.

Also, I have had nothing but trouble with `rvm` on Ubuntu. So, I use `rbenv` (https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv).

To install `rbenv`, do:

```
# remove old rvm
sudo apt-get remove rbenv ruby-bundler ruby-rvm

# common rbenv and rails dependencies, generally good things to have
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev openssl libreadline-dev git-core libnotify-dev \
                     libc6-dev libssl-dev libmysql++-dev libsqlite3-dev \
                     make build-essential libssl-dev libreadline6-dev \
                     libyaml-dev curl

# rbenv installer
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fesplugas/rbenv-installer/master/bin/rbenv-installer | bash

# Add rbenv init to .bashrc
echo 'export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

# Install ruby (this takes many minutes ...~15-ish ...maybe 30 depending on your system)
rbenv install 2.2.2

# Defining which ruby version to use globally
rbenv global 2.2.2
```

Also, Rails development on Ubuntu would be helped by Prax (https://github.com/ysbaddaden/prax), it's like Pow but for Linux and it's written in pure Ruby.

EDIT:

I tried the [`pinteresting`](https://github.com/onemonthrails/pinteresting) app and it too started up fine for me:

```
# I had to install a 2.0.0 version of Ruby 
rbenv install 2.0.0-p645

cd ~
git clone https://github.com/onemonthrails/pinteresting
cd pinteresting
echo '2.0.0-p645' > .ruby-version
bundle install
rake db:migrate
rails server
```